# Bit syntax: Default size in pattern matching?

Tags: erlang

According to Programming Erlang(2nd), bottom of p. 103:

> The value of Size specifies the size of the segment. The default value
>   depends on the type.  For an integer it is 8, for a float it is 64,
>   and for a binary it is the size of the binary.  ***In pattern matching,
>   this default value is valid only for the very last element***.

Doesn't the following example disprove the rule that "the last element in a pattern match is the only one that can employ a a default size":

```
1> Bin = <<97, 98, 99>>.
<<"abc">>

2> <<X/integer, Rest/binary>> = Bin.  %Employs default Size for integer.
<<"abc">>

3> X.
97

4> Rest.
<<"bc">>
```

The [erlang docs](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html) reiterate the same rule stated in Programming Erlang(2nd):

> 4.4 Defaults
>   ...
>   ...
>   The default Size depends on the type. For integer it is 8. For float
>   it is 64. For binary it is all of the binary. ***In matching, this
>   default value is only valid for the very last element.*** All other
>   binary elements in matching must have a size specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, now that I've posted that quote from the docs, I notice it says:

> In matching, this default value is only valid for the very last
>   element. All other ***binary*** elements in matching must have a size
>   specification.

And in fact, I do get an error here:

```
7> f().
ok

8> Bin = <<97, 98, 99>>.            
<<"abc">>

9> <<B/binary, X/integer>> = Bin.   
* 1: a binary field without size is only allowed at the end of a binary pattern
```

The error message there is clearer than anything in the docs and in Programming Erlang(2nd).  So it looks to me like the docs should be rewritten, something like this:

> 4.4 Defaults
>
> [Beginning omitted: <<3.14>> isn't even legal syntax.]
>
> In construction, the default Size depends on the type. For integer it is 8. For float it is 64. For binary it is the actual size of the
>   specified binary:
>
> ```
> 1> Bin = << <<97, 98, 99>>/binary, 17/integer, 3.2/float >>.  
> <<97,98,99,17,64,9,153,153,153,153,153,154>>
>  |<------>| ^|<-------------------------->|
>   binary=24 |           float=64  
>             |        
>         integer=8
>
> 2> size(Bin). % Returns the number of bytes:
> 12            % 3*8 bits + 8 bits + 64 bits = 96 bits => 96/8 = 12 bytes
> ```
>
> In matching, a binary segment without an explicit Size is only allowed at the end of the pattern, and its default Size is the number of bytes remaining in the
>   binary on the right hand side of the match:
>
> ```
> 25> Bin = <<97, 98, 99>>.
> <<"abc">>
>
> 26> << X/integer, Rest/binary >> = Bin.
> <<"abc">>
>
> 27> X.
> 97
>
> 28> Rest.
> <<"bc">>
> ```
>
> All other segments with type binary in a pattern must specify a Size:
>
> ```
> 12> Bin = <<97, 98, 99, 100>>.         
> <<"abcd">>
>
> 13> << B:1/binary, X/integer, Rest/binary >> = Bin. %'unit' defaults to 8 for  
> <<"abcd">>                    %binary type, total segment size is Size * unit  
>
> 14> B.
> <<"a">>
>
> 15> X.
> 98
>
> 16> Rest.
> <<"cd">>
>
> 17> << B2/binary, X2/integer, Rest2/binary >> = Bin. 
> * 1: a binary field without size is only allowed at the end of a binary pattern
> ```

Do I have that right?

Comment: You should probably take this discussion to the erlang-questions mailing list if you think something should be changed in the documentation. See http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-questions